# NF-e em Delphi acessando WSDL

Tags: delphi, xml, nfe, wsdl

NF-e em Delphi acessando WSDL.

Não sou experimente em em acessar servidores em WSDL, nem NFe.

Tenho a disposição alguns métodos encapsulados informado para serem usados em **Delphi**.

O método que estou tentando acessar é este:

```
function  RecepcionarLoteRpsSincrono(const nfseCabecMsg: WideString; const nfseDadosMsg: WideString): WideString; stdcall;
```

Os exemplos que eu tenho são arquivos XML completos, só que eu tenho que utilizar as funções fornecidas, neste caso passar dois parâmetros. Não sei como usar. Preciso saber exatamente o que escrever nesses parâmetros. Eu tenho exemplo de um arquivo XML mas o que eu preciso são dois parâmetros para uma função, sei que o primeiro é o cabeçalho e o segundo são dos Dados.

Já copiei o XML para os parâmetros, parte deles, referente ao cabeçalho fiz o que estava no meu alcance.

Eu faço a chamada:

```
var
  Cabeca, Dados,
  Retorno : WideString;
Begin
  // ... outros códigos
  Cabeca := memCabeca.Text;//TMemo
  Dados := memDados.Text;//TMemo
  Retorno := nfseuse.RecepcionarLoteRpsSincrono(Cabeca, Dados);
  ShowMessage(Retorno);
End;
```

Eu não sei quais são os parâmetros corretos `WideString` que devo passar para `nfseCabecMsg` e `nfseDadosMsg`.

Essa é a mensagem de erro produzido pelo `ShowMesssage`

[image: Resultado do ShowMessage]

Abaixo imagem de parte do **XML** fornecido de exemplo:

[image: Imagem de parte do XML fornecido de exemplo]

Espero que eu tenha sido claro, e passado minha dúvida corretamente.

Obrigado.